# keep array first index element and last index element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array .my array store in like

```
$details = $this->api_model->testw();
```

here mysql query return result array in `$details`.

now I want to keep first index datetime value and last index datetime value

like

```
$first='2010-05-15 11:29:45';
$last='2010-05-26 16:04:24';
```

my array

```
   Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [type] => comment
            [text] => hey
            [datetime] => 2010-05-15 11:29:45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [type] => status
            [text] => oi
            [datetime] => 2010-05-26 15:59:53
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [type] => status
            [text] => yeww
            [datetime] => 2010-05-26 16:04:24
        )

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`end()`](http://php.net/end) and [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset) to get the first and last arrays, and then access the `datetime`  values, like so:

```
// Get the first and last sub-arrays
$first = reset($data);
$last = end($data);

// Create an array containing the datetimes
$result = array($first['datetime'], $last['datetime']);

// Output the contents of the above array
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2010-05-15 11:29:45
    [1] => 2010-05-26 16:04:24
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/120064)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $Arr = Array(Array('id' => 2, 'type' => 'comment', 'text' => 'hey', 'datetime' => '2010-05-15 11:29:45'), Array('id' => 3, 'type' => 'status', 'text' => 'oi', 'datetime' => '2010-05-26 15:59:53'), Array('id' => 4, 'type' => 'status', 'text' => 'yeww', 'datetime' => '2010-05-26 16:04:24'));

        $count = 0;
        $totalcount = count($Arr);

        foreach ($Arr as $Arr1) {
            $count++;
            if ($count == 1 || $count == $totalcount) {
                foreach ($Arr1 as $key1 => $val2) {
                    if ($count == 1 && $key1 == 'datetime')
                        $first = $val2;

                    if ($count == $totalcount && $key1 == 'datetime')
                        $last = $val2;
                }
            }

        }

        echo $first.' - '.$last;
        ?>
```

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use end() and reset() for access first and last element of array, and then access the date time values.

```
 // Get the first and last element of array
```

$first = reset($data);
$last = end($data);